# com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0}

Tags: spring, spring-boot, was

While trying to deploy the springboot 2.7.11 project in IBM Webshere 9, we are receiving this error:

```
`EDT] 000000a9 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0} java.lang.NullPointerException at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.contextDestroyed(WeldInitialListener.java:134) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.managedobject.ManagedObjectListenerWrapper.contextDestroyed(ManagedObjectListenerWrapper.java:138) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1867) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.destroy(WebApp.java:3288) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.destroy(WebAppImpl.java:1561) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:97) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImp`
```

There are already applications with spring boot 2.7.11 on this server, the only difference is that it uses jpa

```
 `<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>`
```